# Photoshop script to take a Smart Object and "Relink to File"

Tags: adobe-photoshop, photoshop-scripting, script

Please help :)

In Photoshop CC under "File > Place Linked..." I can select a file to be placed as a linked layer (layer with a link icon over the layer thumbnail). I would like a Photoshop script to do this same process with a predetermined file path. To clarify, I do **not** want an embedded smart object. It must be linked to the file so if there are changes to the original linked file I can go to Menu: "Layer > Smart Objects > Update All Modified Content" and it will update the linked layer with the any new changes. The layer should look like this:

[image]

I was able to add a layer, convert it to a smart object, and replace it with a provided file. Only thing left is to have it be a linked layer rather than an embedded smart object.

If more info/screen shots are required please reach out, Any help is greatly appreciated!

```
var convertToSmartObject = function () {
    var idnewPlacedLayer = stringIDToTypeID('newPlacedLayer');
    executeAction(idnewPlacedLayer, undefined, DialogModes.NO);
};
var replaceSmartObjectContents = function (filePath, smartObj) {
    app.activeDocument.activeLayer = smartObj;
    var idplacedLayerReplaceContents = stringIDToTypeID("placedLayerReplaceContents");
    var desc3 = new ActionDescriptor();
    var idnull = charIDToTypeID("null");
    desc3.putPath(idnull, new File(filePath));
    var idPgNm = charIDToTypeID("PgNm");
    desc3.putInteger(idPgNm, 1);
    executeAction(idplacedLayerReplaceContents, desc3, DialogModes.NO);
};
var doc = app.activeDocument;

// Add a layer, this will now be the active layer
doc.artLayers.add();  

// Convert active layer to Smart Object
convertToSmartObject(); 

// replace a provided layer with a provided file path
replaceSmartObjectContents("~/Path/To/File.ai", doc.activeLayer);
```

Comment: I answered a similar question on SO — you'll want a `relinkSO` function https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66261365/photoshop-scripting-relink-smart-object/66355072#66355072

Comment: @SergeyKritskiy Wonderful, that is just what I needed - Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

If any one finds this, I've updated my script with the function linked by @SergeyKritskiy

```
function convertToSmartObject() {
    var idnewPlacedLayer = stringIDToTypeID('newPlacedLayer');
    executeAction(idnewPlacedLayer, undefined, DialogModes.NO);
} // end of convertToSmartObject()

function relinkSO(path) {
    var desc = new ActionDescriptor();
    desc.putPath(charIDToTypeID('null'), new File(path));
    executeAction(stringIDToTypeID('placedLayerRelinkToFile'), desc, DialogModes.NO);
} // end of relinkSO()

// Target current document
var doc = app.activeDocument;

// Add a layer, this will now be the active layer
doc.artLayers.add();  

// Convert active layer to Smart Object
convertToSmartObject(); 

// Relink active layer(smart object) with a provided file path
relinkSO("~/Path/To/File.ai");
```

Answer (score 0):

I've tried something similar, but can't find a method to get around or bypass camera raw when relinking the file. Can you help me? is it even possible?